# Extracting Email Address & Name From Forwarded Emails

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, string-parsing

I'm trying to use Google Script to extract email address and name from forwarded emails that I've filed under a specific label.

The emails look like this:

From: Person A 
Sent: Sunday, September 22, 2019 8:00 PM
To: Other, Email 
Subject: Forwarded Email

BODY

They have all have been forwarded to this specific inbox. Therefore the headers actually include my other email address I forwarded from.

I've sorted over 2000 emails and now for each of the labels I want to extract the name of the sender (Person A) and their email address (person@gmail.com) in a spreadsheet. Preferably, I can have the first and last name in separate cells (e.g. Person | A | email address)

The code I have thus far is below:

```
function processInboxToSheet() {

  // Have to get data separate to avoid google app script limit!

  var start = 0;
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LABEL");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var result = [];



  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    var content = messages[0].getPlainBody();

    // implement your own parsing rule inside
    if (content) {
      var tmp;
      tmp = content.match(/From:\n([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var name = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No name';

      tmp = content.match(/<\n([A-Za-z0-9@.]+)/);
      var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No email';

      sheet.appendRow([name, email]);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
};
```

I only get No name and No email as output so something is not quite working in the code. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you tried using a debugger with your code?

Comment: In addition to Michiel Leegwater's correct answer, I would like to point out that message metadat, such as  `To`, `From`, `Subject`, `Message ID` etc. is not located in body, but in the header of the message. You can retrieve it manually with e.g. `messages[0].getHeader("From")`

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the plain body, it doesn’t contain to and from. It only contains the message body. The API has methods `getTo()` and `getFrom()` that contains what you want to parse. See [the API for GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message.html) for more details.